# Representing 2D objects in 4D

Tags: geometry

What is the general quation of a 2D object, e.g. a surface in 4D?

I read, that while a line is representable in 2D using the general equation of degree one ($ax + by + c = 0$), in 3D, one needs a system of equations.

In 3D, the general equation of one degree is a plane ($ax + by + cz + d = 0$).

The general equation of second degrees are curves in 2D, and surfaces of revolution in 3D.

I wonder, how does one represent a 2D object in 4D? Do we need a set of equations? How do they look like?

PS : is there a list of objects which are solutions of general equations of first, second and third degree in 4D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, every time you introduce an equation, you go down 1 dimension. So in 4D space, to represent a 2D object you need 2 equations.

For example, if you take two linear equations: $$\begin{cases} Ax+By+Cz+Dw=E\\Fx+Gy+Hz+Iw=J \end{cases}$$then you generally get a 2D plane. (I say generally, because it could also be a 3D space, for example of both equations are identical, or absolutely nothing, for example if one of the equations is $0=1$... But for "generic" choices of coefficients you'll get a plane.)

However, this is not the only case of a 2D surface. Another example might be the 2D sphere embedded in 4D space, one possible instance of which is the following:$$\begin{cases} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1 \\ w = 0 \end{cases}$$

This is a sphere, which is obtained by 2 equations, one of which is 2nd degree and another is linear. Another thing you could look at is the following $$\begin{cases} x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\ z^2 + w^2 = 1 \end{cases}$$which algebraically is two "independent" circles. This surface is known as the [Clifford torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus) and is topologically a 2-dimensional torus.

Those examples above are called "algebraic surfaces", because they are obtained as the solution set of algebraic (polynomial) equations. The first one (a plane) is a degree 1 surface, the others are degree 2. However, not all surfaces are algebraic. For example, consider the following: $$\begin{cases}\sin (\pi x) = 0 \\ \sin (\pi y) = 0\end{cases}$$
This surface is a union of infinitely many planes, and contains all points $(x,y,z,w)$ for which $x, y$ are integers.

The most general case is obtained by the definition of a 2-dimensional [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) inside 4-dimensional space. For some manifolds, it is hard or not fruitful to give equations that describe them.

Comment: One question : Yuo write: 
In general, every time you introduce an equation, you go down 1 dimension. In this sense, a line in three dimension should need two equations, but generally, one uses three (the vecotorial form of the equation $\arrow{v} = \arrow{s} + \alpha \arrow{r} $ can be split to three equations)

Comment: Is what I commented correct?

Comment: @Sean, those aren't equations that are satisfied by points on the line. Those are a parameterization of the line by a single parameter $\alpha$. You need to parameterize 3 variables $x, y, z$ (and in 4D space, 4 variables $x, y, z, w$). However, if you want a non-parametric set of equations that is satisfied by all points on the line and nothing else, then you need 2 equations in 3D space or 3 equations in 4D space.

Comment: Excellent thank you. This answer actually does provide me some further insight, so I will select this as the best answer.

Comment: also, how is that representation of a line using two equation caled?

Comment: I don't know if it has a special name. The idea is the following: Let's say we're at 3D space. Then a line has two perpendicular directions. (If you place a person in the space so the line goes through his stretched-out arms, then the perpendicular directions are "forward" and "up" from the person's point of view. Note this is arbitrary and more choices may be made...) The two equations represent these perpendicular directions, since a linear equation is $(x,y,z) \cdot v = c$ where $v$ is a direction vector. $(x,y,z) \cdot v$ is constant if and only if the line is perpendicular to $v$.

Answer (score 1):

For a line in 4D, it needs to be represented by parametric equations, like a 3D space curve does. A 4D space curve would have 4 parametric equations:

$\frac {x-t}{a}=\frac {y-t}{b}=\frac {z-t}{c}=\frac {w-t}{d} $

Where $<a, b, c, d> $ is a 4D vector

Comment: Yes, I read that too, but what about a 2D object, e.g. a 2D plane.

Comment: Well the equation of a plane in vector form is: $ {n} \bullet {v}=0$ where $ n $ is the normal vector to the plane. In 4D $ n $ and $ v $ are both 4D vectors.

Comment: @dylan7 in 4D, that would be the equation for a hyperplane (3D).

Comment: @Yoni Rozenshein Ah, got it, so you need two equations like you said.